# Distribute elements based on percentages

Tags: python, algorithm

Let's say that I want to distribute a number of items (n) into an array of fixed size (x).
The difficult part is that I have to distribute the items using a flexibility array.

Assuming that `x = 4`, `n = 11` and `flexibility = [20, 20, 30, 30]` with `len(flexibility) == x`.

My question is:
How can I distribute the n elements in an array of length equal to x using the percentage defined in f?

What I want at the end is something like:

```
n = 11
x = 4
flexibility = [20, 20, 30, 30]
distributed = distribute_elements_in_slots(n, x, flexibility)
print(distributed)
# distributed = [2, 2, 3, 4]
```

In the case of equal flexibility values, the final result will depend on the rule that we decide to apply to use all the item. In the previous case, the final result will be good with [2, 2, 3, 4] and with [2, 2, 4, 3].

**Edit**: An example of the method that I want to have is as follows:

```
def distribute_elements_in_slots(n, x, flexibility=[25,25,25,25]):
    element_in_slots = []

    element_per_percentage = x / 100

    for i in range(x):
        element_in_slots.append(round(slots_per_point_percentage * flexibility[i])
```

**Edit 2**: One of the solutions that I found is the following:

```
def distribute_elements_in_slots(n, x, flexibility=[25,25,25,25]):
    element_in_slots = [f * n / 100 for f in flexibility]

    carry = 0
    for i in range(len(element_in_slots)):
        element = element_in_slots[i] + carry
        element_in_slot[i] = floor(element)
        carry = element- floor(element)

    if np.sum(element_in_slots) < n:
        # Here the carry is almost 1
        max_index = element_in_slots.index(max(flexibiliyt))
        appointments_per_slot[max_index] = appointments_per_slot[max_index] + 1
```

This will distribute almost evenly the slots based on the flexibility array.

Comment: What did you try to solve this question, can u provide that code

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I've added my initial, wrong, solution.

Comment: Can you explain the output `[2,2,3,4]`?

Comment: As I said, that is what I would like to have. 
Distribution of the elements that follow the flexibility. The 4 is because it can happen to have another element that we want to add.

Comment: What makes `[2, 2, 3, 4]` the correct answer, rather than `[2, 3, 4, 3]`?  I would think that either is acceptable?

Comment: @Prune you're right. As I said the final result depends on where we decide to put the remaining item.

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is split the number 11 according to certain percents given in the array so initially it becomes `percentage * number(11)`. Then we get remainder and put assign it somewhere which in your case is the last element.

```
In [10]: [i*n/100 for i in f]
Out[10]: [2.2, 2.2, 3.3, 3.3]

In [11]: b=[i*n/100 for i in f]

In [12]: rem = sum(b) - sum(map(int,b))


In [13]: rem
Out[13]: 1.0

In [24]: b= list(map(int,b))

In [26]: b[-1] +=rem

In [27]: b
Out[27]: [2, 2, 3, 4.0]
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you! This is working but in some cases, it returns wrong results.
For example if `f = [24, 26, 26, 24]` with `n = 10` it returns `b = [2, 2, 2, 4]` instead of `b = [2, 3, 3, 2]`.

Comment: @spassador yeah,it depends on where you add the remainder

Answer (score 1):

As Albin Paul did, we need to allocate the whole-number amount for each slot's percentage.  The leftovers need to be allocated, largest first.

```
def distribute_elements_in_slots(total, slots, pct):
    # Compute proportional distribution by given percentages.
    distr = [total * pct[i] / 100 for i in range(slots)]
    # Truncate each position and store the difference in a new list.
    solid = [int(elem) for elem in distr]
    short = [distr[i] - solid[i] for i in range(slots)]
    print(distr)
    print(solid)
    print(short)

    # allocate leftovers
    leftover = int(round(sum(short)))
    print(leftover)
    # For each unallocated item,
    #   find the neediest slot, and put an extra there.
    for i in range(leftover):
        shortest = short.index(max(short))
        solid[shortest] += 1
        short[shortest] = 0
        print("Added 1 to slot", shortest)

    return solid


n = 11
x = 4
flexibility = [20, 20, 30, 30]
distributed = distribute_elements_in_slots(n, x, flexibility)
print(distributed)
# distributed = [2, 2, 3, 4]
```

Output:

```
[2.2, 2.2, 3.3, 3.3]
[2, 2, 3, 3]
[0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3]
1
Added 1 to slot 2
[2, 2, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an [apportionment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apportionment) problem, which has different ways of being solved. See [Mathematics of apportionment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_apportionment).

@prune answer implements the [Largest Remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_remainder_method) or Hamilton Method.

There are other methods, and some simple examples provided by the US Census Bureau can be found [here](https://www.census.gov/history/www/reference/apportionment/methods_of_apportionment.html).

There are Python libraries available at pypi.org that implement different methods:

- [apportionment](https://pypi.org/project/apportionment/)
- [apportionpy](https://pypi.org/project/apportionpy/)

Comment: [Don't include links except to support what you've written](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35181755)