# Allocate elements in python list with specific probobility

Tags: python, loops, iterator, distribution

Assume, I have a specific proportions of slots `proportion = [30,30,20,10,10]`and I want to feed it with `1` element and get it allocated one by one. For example, we start with `[0,0,0,0,0]` and add `1` we get `[1,0,0,0,0]`. What I have so far is that (based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56439598/distribute-elements-based-on-percentages) answer):

```
def distribute_elements_in_slots(total, slots, pct):
    distr = [total * pct[i] / 100 for i in range(slots)]
    solid = [int(elem) for elem in distr]
    short = [distr[i] - solid[i] for i in range(slots)]
    leftover = int(round(sum(short)))
    for i in range(leftover):
        shortest = short.index(max(short))
        solid[shortest] += 1
        short[shortest] = 0
    return solid
```

To feed 1 element at the time I've generated the list on 1's:

```
randomlist = []
for i in range(0,30):
    n = random.randint(1,1)
    randomlist.append(n)
print(randomlist)
```

And addition function to loop over that list:

```
x = 5
flexibility = [30, 30, 20, 10 ,10]
total = 0
cars = 0 
for n in randomlist:
    cars += 1
    total += n
    distributed = distribute_elements_in_slots(total, x, flexibility)
    print(distributed)
```

But the broblem is this fucnction does not remeber the previous step.

```
1-[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2-[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
3-[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
4-[1, 1, 1, 1, 0] - on this step we have 4 elements in 4 slots.
5-[2, 2, 1, 0, 0] - on this step we took 1 from the fourth element and "gave" it to second.
```

But I want it it be like this:

```
1-[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2-[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
3-[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
4-[1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
5-[2, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: `randint(1, 1)` always returns `1`, so basically your `randomlist` contains 30 ones and your final loop is just weird way to iterate over range from 1 to 30 and pass current index to `distribute_elements_in_slots` with some unknown `x` and `flexibility`.

Comment: @Olvin Roght Thank you for pointing that out! I've forgot to add some additional information (added `flexibility` and `x`)

Comment: Why not just use `weights` argument of [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices)? E.g. `choices(range(5), weights=[30,30,20,10,10], k=30)` will return you list of indexes generated randomly according to weights, so you just need to generate list (`[indexes.count(i) for i in range(5)]`).

Comment: there is nothing in your rules that says that the sequence is incorrect, the proportional can only be increasingly approximated as more slots are filled, so your code might actually provide the 'best fit'

Comment: It actually return the 'best proportion', but I want it to remember the previous step as well and allocate the new item according to previouse distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple code gives a slot filling sequence without reallocations:

```
slots = 5
dist = np.array([0]*slots)
proportion = np.array([30,30,20,10,10])
for i in range(0,30):
    total = max(dist.sum(),1)
    prop = dist/total*100
    error = proportion - prop
    idx = np.argmax(error)
    dist[idx] += 1
    print(dist)

[1 0 0 0 0]
[1 1 0 0 0]
[1 1 1 0 0]
[1 1 1 1 0]
[1 1 1 1 1]
[2 1 1 1 1]
[2 2 1 1 1]
[2 2 2 1 1]
[3 2 2 1 1]
[3 3 2 1 1]
[4 3 2 1 1]
[4 4 2 1 1]
[4 4 3 1 1]
[4 4 3 2 1]
[4 4 3 2 2]
[5 4 3 2 2]
[5 5 3 2 2]
[5 5 4 2 2]
[6 5 4 2 2]
[6 6 4 2 2]
[7 6 4 2 2]
[7 7 4 2 2]
[7 7 5 2 2]
[7 7 5 3 2]
[7 7 5 3 3]
[8 7 5 3 3]
[8 8 5 3 3]
[8 8 6 3 3]
[9 8 6 3 3]
[9 9 6 3 3]
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the brilliant answer! It works just fine. Hopefully, I will be able to comprehense it.